# Boostrap 3 affix plugin stops working when body 100%

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have my footer always at the bottom of the page like here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

I'm also using affix plugin so that when scrolling down navbar will (stick) to the top of the browser window when scrolling. However whenever I add

```
body {
height: 100%
}
```

affix stops working. what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a plugin:

**-1-** Use the **navbar-fixed-top** class in your navbar, eg `div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"`

**-2-** Make sure your page has the correct structure (for Bootstrap 3 it is) :

```
<body>

<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
page content here  
</div>  <!-- end wrap -->  

<div id="footer">
  sticky footer here
</div>  <!-- end footer -->  

</body>
```

**-3-** css is

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
/* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
/* Negative indent footer by its height */
margin: 0 auto -60px;
/* Pad bottom by footer height */
padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
height: 60px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

That's it! Note that the CSS and page structure has changed somewhat from Bootstrap 2

Good luck!